# How to check if there's only numbers in string

Tags: string, if-statement, numbers, pascal

how to check if there is only numbers in the string?

I want to skip some code with goto if there's only numbers in the string.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean numbers `['0'..'9']` as chars or numbers as tokens `'124 1489 9842132 545478'` ? Your Q. lacks of accuracy, put a typical example of a string you'd have to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
    i := StrToInt( str );
except
    { str is NOT an integer }
end;
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to check if theres ONLY numbers in the string.

if (sText[i] < '0') or (sText[i] > '9') then
Begin
 if ( sText[i] <> ' ') then
  iChars := iChars + 1;
End;

if ( iChars <= 0) then
 goto OnlyNumbers;

Comment: for i := 1 to lenght(s) do if not s[i] in ['0'..'9'] then raise exception("")

Answer (score 0):

A simple google: [Pascal Help](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/strtoint.html)

> StrToInt
>
> Convert a string to an integer value.
>
> Declaration
>
> Source position: sysstrh.inc line 113
>
> function StrToInt(   const s: string ):Integer; Description
>
> StrToInt will convert the string Sto an integer. **If the string
>   contains invalid characters or has an invalid format, then an
>   EConvertError is raised.**
>
> To be successfully converted, a string can contain a combination of
>   numerical characters, possibly preceded by a minus sign (-). Spaces
>   are not allowed.
>
> The string S can contain a number in decimal, hexadecimal, binary or
>   octal format, as described in the language reference. For enumerated
>   values, the string must be the name of the enumerated value. The name
>   is searched case insensitively.
>
> For hexadecimal values, the prefix '0x' or 'x' (case insensitive) may
>   be used as

Comment: (to avoid exceptions but return a boolean true on success use trystrtoint)